# High-Five Mr. Spitz

Tags: software

Just tried out your Sound Doodle.  Very enjoyable.  Still figuring out some of the functionality, but I likes it.

*Doffs Hat*

Answer (score 1):

Andrew is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, I have had some fun too, Andrew, good on yer!  :)

Answer (score 0):

It is fantastic!!! Well done bru. Going to get the students to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like fun.  Any thought about a PC port for us Windows Heathens?

Comment: Sadly no... Sorry! It's a crazy amount of work for me to port it. Maybe one day :-)